# Android Studio - Execution failed for task ':assets_audio_player:compileDebugKotlin Gradle build failed

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, updates

Android Studio Version - Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1 Update - 7 August 2021

Can anyone facing this error - spend the whole day but couldn't find any solution.

e: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel.(LanguageLevel.java:25)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.(CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.java:26)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.(JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.java:42)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.(KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.kt:26)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:121)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:425)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:226)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:152)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:286)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:114)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @5bb4f7d1
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:252)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:269)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.DynamicBundle.(DynamicBundle.java:22)
... 38 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':assets_audio_player:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.